# How to create a document element in background.js when using Manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, domdocument, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Previously I'd been using Manifest V2 and like the below code I was trying to track an event and send a request to Google Analytics and I never had a problem.

```
if (request.action == "quick_popup_clicked") {
  (function () {
    var ga = document.createElement("script");
    ga.type = "text/javascript";
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = "./js/ga.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })(_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "quick_popup", "clicked"]));
}
```

But after upgrading Manifest V2 to the V3 I'm getting an error that said `document is not defined`.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: There's no way. Service worker doesn't have DOM. Try using [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts).

Comment: @wOxxOm when I used importScripts I've got this error: ```Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'```

Comment: It's because GoogleAnalytics isn't compatible with ManifestV3 service worker. You'll have to use it in a visible page like the popup or the options page.